# Detailed tutorial for DApp programming

Tags: truffle, dapp-development, dapps

I am new to node js and I tried to follow some tutorials to understand it. But, when I started writing DApp code, I get lot of errors like this ([calling smart contract functions from app.js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46054/calling-smart-contract-functions-from-app-js)). I face issues understanding why it don't see deployed as a function. Can some one suggest me a best tutorial for starting DApp coding?

Thanks

Comment: this tutorial helped me, but it is quite limited and you will need to expand your knowledge right away after you finish it by trying to code more Dapp ideas. 
https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2
it has 3 parts, some of which you may not be able to do due to the need of real ether.

Comment: You used the truffle tag, have you done the truffle pet shop tutorial? It's pretty straightforward and it's rather easy to start from there and use your contract instead of the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and most complete tutorial about creating Dapps on ethereum I found so far is this one:
https://www.udemy.com/ethereum-and-solidity-the-complete-developers-guide/

This course starts with basics of ethereum and solidity, so if you already have some experience you can skip it, but I really suggest you don't as the author of the course is great at explaining stuff and you may gain better understanding of the things you already know.

In later sections author creates Dapps from scratch with logic in Solidity and frontend in React. If you are not familiar with React, that's not a problem as basic course of React is included in the last section of the course. In this course you can also learn a lot about web3.js, Metamask and Remix. I really enjoyed that tutorial and can recommend it to anyone who is starting his/her journey with Solidity.

Unfortunately this is not a free course. I don't know what will be the price for you because prices on Udemy vary depending on user history of purchasing courses.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the Truffle [pet shop tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop). It's pretty straightforward and it's not so hard to plug your own contract when you start to understand what everything does.

At the end of it you end up with something pretty solid and easily adaptable.

I had to make my own research when I was stuck, like with everything, but I didn't need another tutorial to make my Dapp (except when I had to delve into more specific concepts like tokens, etc.)

But I assume you've already done it, I'm not sure what else you're expecting.

Comment: I followed the pet shop tutorial and ended up with errors as i put in my previous post.

Comment: @KKolluru I saw it, I wrote an answer, try it and let me know how it goes :)